# I was cloning my os to external drive and computer shut down now disk is no show

Tags: hard-drive

I was clowning my c drive to external drive with mini tool it was almost done and pc lost power now the external hhd does not show anywhere, not in disk managment or device manager or anywhere tried cmd listdisk stuff but nothing

Comment: And what is the problem? Might be best to just reformat the external drive and start the process again. If the drive completely doesn’t show up, try on a different USB port. If the drive is utterly lost, don’t know what else to say.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Probably lost, assuming the *"does not show anywhere, not in disk managment or device manager"* is true (and ignoring the typos).

Comment: Given it is an external disk, have you unplugged it and plugged it back in? Sometimes that is required in order to do anything with it. Make sure it it has no power and usb is not connected so the drive can boot  up normally again. If that doesn't work, then it was writing during the powerloss to a location on the drive that was critical and the drive is dead.

Comment: Probably just a corrupt partition. Does the device show inside disk part? Open CMD as admin, type `diskpart`, then type `list disk`. Does your external drive show up there? If it does, then type `select disk x`, where `x` is the number corresponding to your external drive, and then type `clean`. This will wipe the external disk back to a partitionless storage device, after which you will be able to re-initialize the disk within disk management so you can start fresh with mini tool.

Comment: @Mastaxx Things that don't show up in Disk Management or Device Manager won't show up anywhere else.